# broadcast receiver prei-nstalled apps

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I know that in applications developed by third parties to get on google play, BroadcastReceiver not begin to run until the user enters the application.

I would like to know what happens in applications that are pre installed on the phone, because I am developing an application of this type. They start to listen from the beginning or require the user to enter the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System apps receive broadcasts, even if they are in force stopped state or have not been started even once

Edit : 
PackageManagerService has a ActivityIntentResolver which resolves all the broadcasts. So if you check the override for isFilterStopped, it is excluding system apps from stopped packages.

Below is the comment you can search in AOSP:

```
// System apps are never considered stopped for purposes of
// filtering, because there may be no way for the user to
// actually re-launch them.
```